# Cannot find namespace when using reexported class in generics

Tags: typescript

First of all I was not sure what title should I give to this question. If someone has better idea feel free to edit it.

I have a `models` folder in which I have a set of model classes:

```
export default class Dog {
    id: string;
}

export default class Cat {
    id: string;
}
```

In same folder I also have an `index.ts` file exporting them like this:

```
import Cat from './Cat';
import Dog from './Dog';

export default {Cat, Dog};
```

The idea is that in other places of my app I should be to import all models at once instead of importing them separately:

```
import models from '../models';
```

This works as expected - I can create new instances like this:

```
let dog = new models.Dog();
```

Unfortunately it is not working when I try to use it as a generic argument like this:

```
class Foo extends Bar<models.Cat> {
}
```

When I try to do it I get following error: `TS2503:Cannot find namespace 'models'`.

Is there a way to get this working for generic parameters?